# Bar-Plot with two bars and two y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, grouped-bar-chart

I have a DataFrame looking like this:

```
     amount     price
age
A     40929   4066443
B     93904   9611272
C    188349  19360005
D    248438  24335536
E    205622  18888604
F    140173  12580900
G     76243   6751731
H     36859   3418329
I     29304   2758928
J     39768   3201269
K     30350   2867059
```

Now I'd like to plot a bar-plot with the age on the x-axis as labels. For each x-tick there should be two bars, one bar for the amount, and one for the price. I can get this working by using simply:

```
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

The problem is the scaling. The prices are so much higher that I can not really identify the amount in that graph, see:

[image]

Thus I'd like a second y-axis. I tried it using:

```
df.loc[:,'amount'].plot(kind='bar')
df.loc[:,'price'].plot(kind='bar',secondary_y=True)
```

but this just overwrites the bars and does NOT place them side-by-side.
Is there any way to do this without having to access the lower-level matplotlib (which would be possible obviously by placing the bars side by side manually)?

For now, I'm using two single plots within subplots:

```
df.plot(kind='bar',grid=True,subplots=True,sharex=True);
```

resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Using the new pandas release (0.14.0 or later) the below code will work. To create the two axis I have manually created two matplotlib axes objects (`ax` and `ax2`) which will serve for both bar plots.

When plotting a Dataframe you can choose the axes object using `ax=...`. Also in order to prevent the two plots from overlapping I have modified where they align with the `position` keyword argument, this defaults to `0.5` but that would mean the two bar plots overlapping.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = StringIO("""     amount     price
A     40929   4066443
B     93904   9611272
C    188349  19360005
D    248438  24335536
E    205622  18888604
F    140173  12580900
G     76243   6751731
H     36859   3418329
I     29304   2758928
J     39768   3201269
K     30350   2867059""")

df = pd.read_csv(s, index_col=0, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)

fig = plt.figure() # Create matplotlib figure

ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # Create matplotlib axes
ax2 = ax.twinx() # Create another axes that shares the same x-axis as ax.

width = 0.4

df.amount.plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, width=width, position=1)
df.price.plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax2, width=width, position=0)

ax.set_ylabel('Amount')
ax2.set_ylabel('Price')

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 94):

You just need to write: *df.plot( kind= 'bar'**, secondary_y= 'amount'**)*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
s = StringIO("""     amount     price
A     40929   4066443
B     93904   9611272
C    188349  19360005
D    248438  24335536
E    205622  18888604
F    140173  12580900
G     76243   6751731
H     36859   3418329
I     29304   2758928
J     39768   3201269
K     30350   2867059""")
df = pd.read_csv(s, index_col=0, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)

_ = df.plot( kind= 'bar' , secondary_y= 'amount' , rot= 0 )
plt.show()
```

[image: Secondary_Y_axis]

Answer (score 9):

Here is an other method:

- create all the bars in left axes
- move some bars to the right axes by change it's `transform` attribute

Here is the code:

```
import pylab as pl
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 2), columns=["left", "right"])
df["left"] *= 100

ax = df.plot(kind="bar")
ax2 = ax.twinx()
for r in ax.patches[len(df):]:
    r.set_transform(ax2.transData)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 2);
```

here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by InLaw you should use `secondary_y = 'amount'`

To add to his answer here is how to set the **ylabels** for the two axis:

```
df.plot.bar(figsize=(15,5), secondary_y= 'amount')

ax1, ax2 = plt.gcf().get_axes() # gets the current figure and then the axes

ax1.set_ylabel('price')

ax2.set_ylabel('amount')
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes `plt.bar(x,y)` provides more flexibility:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10, 8))
width = 0.4 # Width of a bar 

ax2 = ax.twinx()

vals=df['series1']
x=list(df['xseries1'])[:]
bar1 = ax.bar(x, vals, width = width,color='darkblue')

vals2 = df['series2']
x2=list(df['xseries1']+width)[:]
bar2 = ax2.bar(x2, vals2, width = width,color='darkorange')

ax.set_ylabel("whatever1",color='darkblue')
ax2.set_ylabel("whatever2",color='darkorange')
ax.set_xlabel("Fiscal Year")

#change y limits to give more room:
scale=1.1
max_y_lim = max(vals)*scale
min_y_lim = min(vals)
ax.set_ylim(min_y_lim, max_y_lim);
max_y_lim2 = max(vals2)*scale
min_y_lim = min(vals2)
ax2.set_ylim(min_y_lim2, max_y_lim2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).