# pandas resample changes numerical value of index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

**Background**: I'm trying to plot dissimilar `pd.Series` on the same axes. One of the `Series` has a much higher data rate, so I want to filter it (`series.resample`) and reduce the noise. The problem is, after resampling, it no longer plots on top of the low-data-rate `Series`.

EDIT: In addition, the data have different y-axis scales, so I'm using `secondary_y=True`. This somehow seems to be important, but I'm not sure why.

**Proximate cause**: I realized that the automatic x-axis limits coming back from matplotlib are very different after resampling. This means that the underlying numerical value of the index is changing. But I can't find anything in the pandas documentation about this.

EDIT: The xlim() output in the following code snippet demonstrates the change of x-axis limits. @masasa below points out that by issuing the plot commands together, both `ds` and `ds_filt` will plot successfully on the same axes. This is true even with `secondary_y=True`. However, my other `Series` does not plot successfully with `ds_filt` (not shown here because I don't even know how to reproduce the failure).

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.date_range('20190101', '20190103', freq='10s')
arr = np.random.randn(idx.size).cumsum()
ds = pd.Series(index=idx, data=arr)

ds.plot()
plt.xlim()

>>> (1546300800.0, 1546473600.0)

ds_filt = ds.resample('12H').mean()
ds_filt.plot()
plt.xlim()

>>> (429528.0, 429576.0)
```

Comment: Solved using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685887/secondary-y-true-changes-x-axis-in-pandas). Root cause is still not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I might didnt understand your problem correctly , but your 2 plots are not on the same figure, thats why they are seperated,
if you do the following :

```
ds.plot()
ds.resample('12H').mean().plot()
plt.xlim()
```

youll get a merged graph
[image]

Comment: You haven't explained the xlim() output in my original code snippet. But your result is interesting in itself. Let me go back and edit my post to clarify.

Comment: What you saw is the time range in Unix time (seconds from 1970), when you sampled the data , it divided the time by 12*3600, that’s why your slim changed

Comment: Thanks, but why does it do that? And why does ```secondary_y``` have anything to do with it?

Comment: Unix time is the official time in computers (don’t know the reason , google might know ) machine such as Linux, oracle etc work in Unix time , pandas itself works in Unix time for plots , since the x axis must be numbers (though you can use matplotlib features to convert them to numbers)