# Bar chart with bars from two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, grouped-bar-chart

I have the following dataframes:

```
      import pandas as pd
      import numpy as np
      import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

      df_One = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['1024Sen', '1024Act', '2089Eng', '2089Sen'], 
                             'Qtd_Instrumentation': [18, 5, 25, 10]})


     df_Two = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['1024Sen', '1024Act', '2089Eng', '2089Sen'], 
                   'Qtd_Instrumentation': [14, 1, 22, 10]})
```

I would like to build a bar graph that contains the information from the two data frames, that is, the blue bars indicate the datadrame_One and the vertical red bars indicate the information of the dataframe_Two.

I tried to implement it as follows:

```
       fig, ax = plt.subplots()
       n_group = len(df_One['Category'])
       index = np.arange(n_group)
       bar_width = 0.35
       opacity = 0.8


       rects1 = df_One.plot.bar(x='Category', y='Qtd_Instrumentation', color='r', label = 'Station 
                                One')
       rects2 = df_Two.plot.bar(x='Category', y='Qtd_Instrumentation', color='b', label = 'Station 
                                Two')


       plt.xlabel('Category Instrumentation')
       plt.ylabel('Qtd Instrumentation')

       plt.show()
```

However, this code is wrong, as it designs two bar graphs instead of building just one graph with the two representations.

Does anyone know how I can build this described chart? Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it by choosing the `align='edge'` option and then using positive width for one bar and negative width for another. This will make them aligned next to each other. Also, you have to call `plt.legend()` to display the legends

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

index = np.arange(len(df_One['Category']))
bar_width = 0.35
opacity = 0.8

ax.bar(index, df_One['Qtd_Instrumentation'], color='r', align='edge', width=bar_width, label = 'Station One')
ax.bar(index, df_Two['Qtd_Instrumentation'], color='b', align='edge', width=-bar_width,label = 'Station Two')

# Assign the tick labels
ax.set_xticks(index)
ax.set_xticklabels(df_One['Category'], rotation=90)

plt.xlabel('Category Instrumentation')
plt.ylabel('Qtd Instrumentation')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternative method is the following by using the keyword `position` to place the bars next to each other as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183101/pandas-bar-plot-with-two-bars-and-two-y-axis)

```
df_One.Qtd_Instrumentation.plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, width=bar_width, position=1)
df_Two.Qtd_Instrumentation.plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax, width=bar_width, position=0)

ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 3.5)
ax.set_xticks(index)
ax.set_xticklabels(df_One['Category'])
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I have just one more question: on the complete dataframe I have 15 different Category. When I design the chart, the names overlap. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: @JaneBorges : Use `rotation = 90` while setting the tick labels

Comment: Good idea! In this way the categories are vertical. Just one more question: I tried to increase the graph with: ax.plot (kind = 'bar', figsize = (15.10)). However, it did not increase. Do you know how I can enlarge the graph?

Comment: @JaneBorges : Use `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 10))` and then rest of the code remains the same

Comment: might want a comma in there, e.g. `figsize=(15, 10)`

Comment: @SamMason : Good observation, that was the reason I think it didn't work before for him/her

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest merging the two dataframes first:

```
df_c = pd.merge(df_One, df_Two, on='Category')
df_c.plot.bar(x='Category')
```

gives:

[image: resulting plot]

note that you might want to pass `how='outer'` to merge if you have missing categories.