# Plotting in Pandas with columns that have different scales

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I am trying to plot a data set that looks something like this:

```html
cat    a        b        c
idk    0.47     0.58     1.17
yeet   0.38     0.11     -0.8
skeet  0.03     0.14     0.46
```

Basically, cat is a categorical variable, a and b are variables which are in a range of [0,1] while c is a variable which ranges from [-7,7] and I want a plot where the x axis is the categorical variable with the left y axis being [0,1] corresponding to a&b while the right y axis corresponds to c.

I can plot all of them with the same y axis, which obviously is not ideal and in trying to plot the different y axes with

```html
fig = plt.figure() 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx() 
width = 0.4
wisco_ill_succ.plot.bar(x='cat', y=['a','b'], ax = ax1, position = 0, width = width)
wisco_ill_succ.plot.bar(x='cat', y=['c'], ax = ax2, position = 1, width = width)
```

I get what I want, however the x axes do not line up and it just looks like a jumbled mess:
[image: ew]

I looked at this [Pandas: Bar-Plot with two bars and two y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183101/pandas-bar-plot-with-two-bars-and-two-y-axis) but frankly it has not been very helpful. Is there anything I can do or should I just split it up into two different graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`secondary_y`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html?highlight=secondary_y#plotting-on-a-secondary-y-axis) argument:

```
ax = df.plot.bar(secondary_y=['c'], x='cat', rot=0)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax.right_ax.set_ylim(-7,7)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. Very straightforward coding. Just a note that you have to run the three lines at the same time, was not working when I was testing line-by-line.