# Plotting two variable in the same bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning

I have a dataset having gdp of countries and their biofuel production named "Merging2". I am trying to plot a bar chart of top 5 countries in gdp and in the same plot have the bar chart of their biofuel_production.

I plotted the top gdp's using :

```
yr=Merging2.groupby(by='Years')
access1=yr.get_group(2019)
sorted=access1.sort_values(["rgdpe"], ascending=[False]) #sorting it
highest_gdp_2019=sorted.head(10) # taking the top 5 rgdpe
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
plt.bar(highest_gdp_2019.Countries,highest_gdp_2019.rgdpe, color ='black',width = 0.8,alpha=0.8)
ax.set_xlabel("Countries")
ax.set_ylabel("Real GDP")
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
```

Is there a way to do that in Python ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want two subplots, or do you want both bars next to each other? Either way, check out [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183101/pandas-bar-plot-with-two-bars-and-two-y-axis) which should give you the answer to both. In the second case, you would want a secondary Y-axis (as illustrated in the post)

Comment: my issue is that the countries that are in the top 5 GDP are not the same as top biofuel production. Is there a way I can access those exact countries that are in top 5 gdp and get their biofuel production ? Thank you

Comment: `df.sort_values("GDP")["biofuel"].head(5)`. Is this what you are looking for?