# How can I concatenate two bar charts in a plot with two y-axis using Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, visualization

I'm trying to visualize the mean number of clicks and mean completion time of a given task executed on two different websites. Given the following data:

|  | KUL (Task 1) | Gent (Task 1) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mean Number of clicks | 6.75 | 5.00 |
| Mean Completion time | 25.13 | 20.00 |

For that, I want a two-y-axis bar chart plot that shows a pair of bars comparing the number of clicks and another pair comparing the completion time. I started trying to do it on Google Sheets and the closest I've gotten was this:

I created the table below and selected the 4 series to plot the bar chart in the image.

|  | KUL (Task 1) clicks | KUL (Task 1) time | Gent (Task 1) clicks | Gent (Task 1) time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mean Number of clicks | 6.75 |  | 5.00 |  |
| Mean Completion time |  | 25.13 |  | 20.00 |

[image: two bar charts concatenated]

I know that it's a lot of work for something that could be done in Paint but I'm curious to know if there's a straightforward way to do something like that in Google Sheets.

Comment: Using the first dataframe on the page `df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/q/76296929/7758804', index_col=[0])[0]` and `ax = df.plot(kind='bar')` and [How to plot and annotate a grouped bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63493530/7758804)

Comment: Thanks, @TrentonMcKinney, how do I add the second axis tho? 'Mean Number of clicks' is not a dataframe key.

Comment: `ax = df.plot(kind='bar', secondary_y='Gent (Task 1)')` as per [Bar-Plot with two bars and two y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24183101/7758804)

Comment: Ok, that was simpler than I thought. Thanks for your patience in replying, I look more carefully through SO next time. I've updated the question to make it exclusively about Google Sheets, maybe it's relevant for someone else.